# Force route in express

Tags: javascript, ajax, mongodb, express, asynchronous

Its possible to force a route ?

**Example:**

I have this route **A**:

*notiSchema = notification model*

```
router.get('/set', function(req, res){
    User.findById("userId". function(err, foundUser){
        foundUser.notiSchemaSent.forEach(function(notiSchema, i){
            if(req.user.notifications.length === 0){
                req.user.notifications.unshift(notiSchema);
                req.user.save();
            } else {
                req.user.notifications.forEach(function(userSchema, i){
                    if(req.user.notifications.indexOf(notiSchema) === -1){
                         req.user.notifications.unshift(notiSchema);
                         req.user.save();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

    res.json(req.user.notifications);
});
```

Problem here is that the 'res.json' line is read before the userB is updated

So i created this other route **B**:

```
router.get('/get', middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  res.json(req.user.notifications);
});
```

My **Ajax**:

```
$.get('/set', function(data){
    // I only add a "fa-spin" class here
}).then(function(){
    $.get('/get', function(data){
        $(data).each(function(i, item){
            $('.notDrop').prepend(item);
        });

        // Remove the "fa-spin" class
    });
});
```

But sometimes route "B" is called before "A" ends;

So i want to know if its possible to call the "B" route only after the "A" one gets totally finished.

Comment: You don't need to force a route, nor does that notion even make much sense.  You just need to write your route appropriately so you don't send the response until your async operations are done.  Your `.save()` operation should have a callback or promise that tells you when it's done and only send your response when that's done.  Also, you probably need to stop using `.forEach()` so you can stop the loop when you've found the one you're looking for and then send the response after the `.save()` is done.

Comment: To help you more specifically, we'd have to see real code, not pseudo-code because it's not clear what you're really trying to do in your nested `.forEach()` loops and the details of what you're really trying to do are needed in order to show you how to properly code for the asynchronous operation in the loop.  We, on stackoverflow, are way more helpful with real solutions to real code instead of hypothetical solutions to pseudo-code.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hey, i started using forEach because i read that it can help with Asynchronous  problems. Post updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your route to accumulate all the changes into `req.user.notifications` and then just save once at the end (if the array was modified).  This allows you to then have only one `.save()` operation and to know when it's done by passing a callback to it.

Summary of changes:

1. Accumulate results in the array and only save at the end.
2. Only save if the array was modified.
3. Get rid of the special case for `.length === 0` as that is not needed.
4. Use a callback on `req.user.save()` to know when it's done so we can then. send the response after the save is done.
5. Add error handling for `.save()`.
6. Add error handling for `.findById()`

Here's the code:

```
router.get('/set', function(req, res){
    User.findById("userId", function(err, foundUser){
        if (err) {
           console.log(err);
           res.status(500).send("Error finding user.")
           return;
        }
        let origLength = req.user.notifications.length;
        foundUser.notiSchemaSent.forEach(function(notiSchema, i){
            req.user.notifications.forEach(function(userSchema, i){
                if(req.user.notifications.indexOf(notiSchema) === -1){
                    req.user.notifications.unshift(notiSchema);
                }
            });
        });
        if (req.user.notifications.length !== origLength) {
            req.user.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(500).send("Error saving user notifications.")
                } else {
                    res.json(req.user.notifications);
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.json(req.user.notifications);
        }
    });
});
```

If you change your db code so you get an array of users from the find operation, then you can process those like this:

```
router.get('/set', function(req, res){
    User.find({_id: {$in: arrayOfIds}}, function(err, foundUsers){
        if (err) {
           console.log(err);
           res.status(500).send("Error finding user.")
           return;
        }
        let origLength = req.user.notifications.length;
        foundUsers.forEach(function(foundUser) {
            foundUser.notiSchemaSent.forEach(function(notiSchema, i){
                req.user.notifications.forEach(function(userSchema, i){
                    if(req.user.notifications.indexOf(notiSchema) === -1){
                        req.user.notifications.unshift(notiSchema);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        if (req.user.notifications.length !== origLength) {
            req.user.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(500).send("Error saving user notifications.")
                } else {
                    res.json(req.user.notifications);
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.json(req.user.notifications);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It showed this error Can't set headers after they are sent (but only one time)

Comment: Now it dont show any errors, but it dont add anything to the user database

Comment: @BrunoPigatto - Did you do any debugging to see what path the code follows and see what's actually happening.  I have no ability to run this so you're the one who has to do the debugging if something isn't working.  "didn't worked" does not tell us anything useful to allow us to help you.

Comment: Hey, the problem was that i was testing this using a user with 0 notifications, so the "req.user.notifications.forEach" line wouldn't work, now i fixed it. Thank You!

Comment: @BrunoPigatto - Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Hey, The user can have many subscribed profiles, so before the User.findById i added req.user.subscribed.forEach but the code returns "Can't set headers after they are sent." error. So, I thought about this solution: Make an Ajax call to each of the subscribed profiles. Can you tell me if this is the best aproach ? Or I can make your code work in this scenario? Thank You

Comment: @BrunoPigatto - I don't understand what you want your API to do when there are multiple profiles.  You'd have to start by describing that.  What do you want it to do and what do you want it to return?  This also sounds like it's beyond the scope of the question you asked so maybe you should put the further description of what you're trying to do in a new question.

Comment: Hey. Its like youtube, you can subscribe to many channels.    Example: You subscribed to 5 channels, so every time that you access the website it tells you if the channels that you subscribed have some new videos.   Thats why i added req.user.subscribed.forEach, so i can look at each user you follow and then see if they have any new videos, if so, i send a notification to you.    The code that we have is capable of looking only at one "foundUser", i want to loop the User.findById so i can have more than one "foundUser"

Comment: Are you saying that `findById()` returns an array of separate user objects?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to put more than one id in the place of "userId"? So `findById()` would return an array of users ?

Comment: @BrunoPigatto - What version of mongodb are you running and what db module are you using?  Saving multiple user objects and knowing when they are all done would need to use the promise interface on the database so I need to look at the doc for that.

Comment: Im using mongodb 3.4.2 and mongoose 4.9.5

Comment: @BrunoPigatto - I added an example where there's an array of users.

Comment: Hey! It worked, But i had to change `findById()` to `find({_id: {$in: arrayOfIds}})`. Thank You!!